# Rust: wrapper for jsonwebtoken and serde Deserialize

Tags: rust, jwt, serde

I am writing a Rust wrapper to sign and decode a given struct.

The `create_token` method seems to work: but the `decode_token` return an error on compile time about the lifetimes:

```rust
use jsonwebtoken::{decode, encode, Algorithm, DecodingKey, EncodingKey, Header, Validation};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

const JWT_SECRET: &[u8] = b"secret";

pub struct TokenService;

impl<'de> TokenService {
  pub fn create_token<T: Serialize>(data: T) -> String {
    let header = Header::new(Algorithm::HS512);

    let token = encode(&header, &data, &EncodingKey::from_secret(JWT_SECRET)).unwrap();

    token
  }

  pub fn decode_token<T: Deserialize<'de>>(data: &str) -> T {
    let decoded = decode::<T>(&data, &DecodingKey::from_secret(JWT_SECRET), &Validation::new(Algorithm::HS512)).unwrap();
    //                     ^ Error here
    decoded
  }
}
```

```
the trait bound `for<'de> T: types::errors::_::_serde::Deserialize<'de>` is not satisfied

the trait `for<'de> types::errors::_::_serde::Deserialize<'de>` is not implemented for `T`

note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `rocket::serde::DeserializeOwned` for `T`
```

I am not sure where should I add this missing lifetime. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `T` would need to be constrained to `DeserializeOwned`:

```rust
pub fn decode_token<T: DeserializeOwned>(data: &str) -> T {
    let decoded = decode::<T>(&data, &DecodingKey::from_secret(JWT_SECRET), &Validation::new(Algorithm::HS512)).unwrap();
    decoded
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Also found the option of setting the lifetime as `pub fn decode_token<T>(data: &str) where for<'a> T: Deserialize<'a>`, but `DeserializeOwned` is way cleaner. I imported it from `use serde::de::DeserializeOwned`, if that's incorrect please let me know.

Comment: It is correct @EmilleC. The thing is that `DeserializeOwned` already implies `for<'a> T: Deserialize<'a>`.

Comment: In fact, [this is the only thing `DeserializeOwned` does](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html#impl-DeserializeOwned) (and this is also mentioned [in the serde book](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html)).